# JQuery click event and toggleClass method

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, arrays

I created a simple lottery ticket and I made selector with toggle method.
This is my code.

```
  $( "span" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "span-selected" );
});
```

The toggle functionality works fine but I want to add a limitation so that only 7 numbers can be chosen in one container. Is there a way to achieve this.
Here is my JSBIN > http://jsbin.com/menawu/1/edit?js,output

Comment: I can't go on Jsbin, I imagine when a number is selected when you click on a span ?

Comment: @Alexis 
Hi alex here is codepen https://codepen.io/Karadjordje/pen/Pbjmxy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check if there are already 7 elements checked in that container, like so:

```
$( "span" ).click(function() {
  if (
     $(this).hasClass("span-selected") || 
     (!$(this).hasClass(".span-selected") && $(this).closest(".num-cont").find(".span-selected").length < 7)
  ) {
       $( this ).toggleClass( "span-selected" );
   }
});
```

So your criteria are:

- if it's not selected, check if there are less than 7: if yes, toggle, otherwise don't do anything
- if it is selected, unselect it.

Comment: Very compact, but you are checking `hasClass` twice. This looks like it should be an exclusive or, so you could just check `$(this).hasClass("span-selected") != $(this).closest(".num-cont").find(".span-selected").length < 7`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code;

```
$( "span" ).click(function() {
  if($(this).parent().parent().find('.span-selected').length===7){
    alert('Limit');
  }
  else{
    $( this ).toggleClass( "span-selected" );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

you can cumulate the count of tickets chosen in a variable and allow toggling only when count is less than 7, based on the jQuery hasClass method to check if your span was previously selected:

```
var countTicket = 0;
$( "span" ).click(function() {
  if($(this).hasClass( "span-selected")) {
    countTicket--;
    $( this ).toggleClass( "span-selected" );   
  } else if(countTicket<7) {
    $( this ).toggleClass( "span-selected" );
    countTicket++;
  }
});
```

Comment: This will count the tickets globally, while he needs to do it for each container. It is easier to use the length property.

Answer (score 2):

Here an example, with multiple case for controle your numbers.
You can easily know if it's unselect/select or if more than 7 span are selected by using `hasClass/removeClass/addClass`

```js
$("span").click(function(){

  if($(this).hasClass("selected"))
  {
    $(this).removeClass("selected");
  }
  else{
    if($("span.selected").length<7)
    {
      $(this).addClass("selected");
    }
    else
      console.log("7 span selected");
  }
 
});
```

```css
span{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  margin:10px;
  background-color:#eee;
  display:inline-table;
}

.selected{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

just insert count and max variables

```
var max = 7;
var count = 0;
$("span").click(function() {
    if (count < max) {
        $(this).toggleClass("span-selected");
        count++;
    }
});
```

Comment: Good answer easy to understand but only works for one container.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of selected item using the parent container and count them:

```
$( "span" ).click(function() {
          if($(this).closest('.num-cont').find('.span-selected').length==7){
            alert('Limit');
          }
          else{
            $( this ).toggleClass( "span-selected" );
          }
        });
```